# I want to set when someone mention me bot will respond

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my discord.js bot send messages when someone pings me. How can I do that??

I was trying with that code:

```js
if(message.content === "<@723821826291138611>") {
message.channel.send("Hello, sup? ")
}
```

but that doesn't work. how can I do that?

Comment: Sure that works if that's the only thing in the message. You may be looking for `message.content.includes("<@723821826291138611>")`...

Comment: not workinEverything looks fine but i dont know whyg :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best - and most conventional - way to do this is to check the [MessageMentions#(users|members)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) collection.

```js
const { 
   mentions:{ 
      users,
      repliedUser
   }
} = message;

if (users.has("723821826291138611") && !repliedUser) {
   // Your code
}
```

This will return true if the mentioned is found in *any* order not only first, it's possible for the API to emit the mentions in different orders if multiple mentions were given. I wouldn't recommend searching the `message.content` string either.

Comment: Thank you so much. :)))))

Comment: bro, there was a problem when someone replies to my text it replies to the text. but i don't want that i want when someone mention me it will be reply -_-

Comment: Edited to not account for message replies

Comment: bro not working see these images
Image 1: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/773497644114378793/906149197328318484/unknown.png
Image 2: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/773497644114378793/906149289389076480/unknown.png

Comment: What does `repliedUser` return for both a mention reply and non-mention replies?

Comment: listen when someone mention me it works and when someone reply my text like the image i send you it works. but i want it when someone mention me it should work not replies

Comment: "*when someone mention me it works... want it when someone mention me it should work not replies*" I'm having trouble understanding the flow you want to implement. Regardless, this is now unrelated to the question you've posted. I'd recommend posting a new question for this new problem. Otherwise the flow should be easy to implement with simple logics

Comment: Are you in discord? then join this server i will show you what is the problem https://discord.gg/sRrvTJSw69

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `if(message.content.includes("<@723821826291138611>"))` instead of `if(message.content === "<@723821826291138611>")` to make it work!

But also you can use this code to do it:

```js
let mentioned = message.mentions.members.first();
if(mentioned && mentioned.id == "723821826291138611") {
if(message.mentions.repliedUser) return;
message.channel.send("YOUR_TEXT")
}
```

Comment: not workinEverything looks fine but i dont know whyg :)

Comment: are checking the correct property for your condition?

Comment: Is this is okay 

if(message.content.includes("<@723821826291138611>")) {
message.channel.send("Photon in a double-slit ")
}

Comment: @IrtizaKhanLabib yea, it should work just fine, do you get any errors in console?

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft No i didn't get any errors in console but bot didn't send the message :\

Comment: @IrtizaKhanLabib I updated my answer, try using it instead

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Thank you but there was a problem when someone replies to my text it replies to text. but I don't want that I want when someone mentions me it will be reply -_-

Comment: @IrtizaKhanLabib `if(message.mentions.repliedUser) return;`

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Not working still when anyone replies me it sucks :))